# PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu doesnt accept duplicate keys

Tags: primefaces, selectonemenu

I am migrating data and have some duplicate keys in the list. The drop down seems to overwrite old key values with the newly found key value. example

```
id  name
2   United States of America
69  United States of America
```

i will only get the second one in the drop down menu.

is it possible to make the menu accept duplicates?

Comment: Please, put your selectOneMenu. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: and you talk about keys but in your 'example' it looks like labels...